# Black patches appearing on glass materal in cycles in viewport preview

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, lighting, glass

I have a glass material applied to an object I am rendering in Cycles, but whenever I render it the material generates these black squares around it. the Object is light by an HDRI, however even without the HDRI it still has this issue. I changed the values in the "max bounces" section of the Render Properties tab, but to no effect. I'm stumped, what is causing this? Is there an obvious setting I'm missing?

Any Help would be much appreciated[image]!

Comment: Probably a bug.

Comment: Can you share the blend file? Make sure to include all the texture files.